# Records Created via Connected Apps

Tags: chatter, connected-apps

I am creating FeedItem records after generating an access token via a connected Org. When this feeditem is posted it shows that this is created via My connected app.

Can I query all the FeedItems created by my connected app?

Comment: Hi Gulshan, what have you tried so far? Can you show us some of your code?

Answer (score 3):

The ConnectAPI FeedItem data includes a clientInfo property that describe the application that generated the feed item. However, the documentation does not state that you can filter on this information, so presumably this isn't available. I also checked the [IdeaExchange](http://ideas.salesforce.com/), but I didn't find anything there, either, so you might want to try posting a new idea.